# Regarding transactions in Firestore, if I write to the same document multiple times, will those operations get flattened to a single write?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

If I update `fieldA` of my document and then later in the same transaction update `fieldB`, how many writes will this get counted as when I commit the transaction?

Comment: Are there different `update()` calls? Then 2 writes. Can you update both fields at once? or the 2nd update relies on something else?

Comment: 2nd update relies on a condition and then some more processing so it may or may not happen. If it does count as 2 writes then I'll just have to do some refactoring. Shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I update fieldA of my document and then later in the same transaction update fieldB, how many writes will this get counted as when I commit the transaction?

If you do the update operations, one after another, meaning that you call update() function two times, then you'll have to pay two write operations. However, as @Dharmaraj mentioned in his comment, you can update as many fields as you want, in a [single update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects), and pay a single read.

However, if the second update is based on the processing of the first update, then yes, you'll have to pay two writes.